# How to use jQuery .When .done

Tags: javascript, jquery, promise

I'm trying to run one function after another function completes.

```
 $.when(saveCanvas(canvas)).done(setWallPaper());
```

Each function works fine on it's own but when I run the code above it only runs the first function.

What do I need to change?

Comment: Hard to answer without seeing the actual functions' implementations, but wild guess `$.when(saveCanvas(canvas)).done(setWallPaper);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking back at this now, this seems to be how it works with jQuery:

```js
function f1() {
 alert("function one");
}

$.when( f1() ).done(function() {
  alert("function 1 is done running function two");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Note: This is identical to my method I posted in the question so essentially it should have worked. Though jQuery may have changed over the last 3 years. Most likely was a problem with functions being called.

Answer (score 9):

According to a comment on [another SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11552347/jquery-when-done-dont-work-for-me), `$.when` expects deferred objects as arguments. If you don't pass anything, the callbacks will be invoked immediately.

Does `setWallPaper()` appear to not be working because it is actually being run before `saveCancas(canvas)`? `saveCanvas()` is not actually a [deferred object](http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/), which `when` expects it to be. To make it a deferred object, add `dfr = $.Deferred();` to the beginning of your `saveCanvas()` function and `return dfr.promise();` to the end of it. Check out [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4980394/761793) for more details.

```
function saveCanvas(canvas)
{
    dfr = $.Deferred();
    //Your code
    return dfr.promise();
}
```

Read more: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.when/

Comment: You're right about it running immediately but passing in canvas didn't seem to have an effect.

Comment: @PhilipK Edited my answer to suggest a different solution

Comment: Remember that the promise must be resolved at some point, or the done callback will never fire.

Comment: This answer was very useful for me. Thx a lot!

Comment: I had the same problem.. I just added ``return true;`` to the first function and it works a charm.

Answer (score 2):

another wild guess:

```
$.when(saveCanvas(canvas)).done(function(){
    setWallPaper()
});
```