# Javascript: return fires before promise completes

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, promise

```
function process(hugedirectory) {

        var title = hugedirectory.getTitleEachFile().then(function(caption){            
            console.log(caption);
            return caption;
        });


        return title;       
    }
```

I have an AJAX call which calls this method but right now, it will return nothing.

`console.log(caption)` displays correct and expected value. However, this value is not returned at the end of this method.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15594567/how-to-use-jquery-when-done

Comment: this is not using jquery.

Comment: this is how asynchronous functions work. all data processing resulting from an asynchronous call must be preformed using a callback function

Comment: can you demonstrate an example of that? I am not sure what it means

Comment: what are you doing with the returned value

Comment: I am outputting it to the user after the process() returns the string.

Comment: which library is used to create the promise

Comment: also share the call to `process()`

Comment: The overall understanding of Asynchronous code/callbacks is explained [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-ajax-call-from-a-function).

Comment: Where do you expect `return caption;` to be returned to? It will be returned to the function that calls the callback, which is `.then`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since `process` make use of asynchronous function calls, you cannot return a value from the method.

The solution to this kind of problem is to make use of callback functions as given below

```
function process(hugedirectory, callback) {
    hugedirectory.getTitleEachFile().then(function(caption){            
        console.log(caption);
        callback(caption)
    });
}

process(hugedirectory, function(title){
    //Do something with title
})
```

In this instead of returning the title from `process` we pass a callback function to `process` which is getting called when the async call is completed and the resulted `title` value is passed to the callback function.

Comment: "Since process make use of asynchronous function calls, you cannot return a value from the method". This statement is not correct. A basic understanding of Deferreds/Promises should lead you re reconsider.

Comment: Arun, whereas your solution is perfectly OK, returning a promise from the function is also a viable approach. For example, the function could be as simple as `function process(hugedirectory) { return hugedirectory.getTitleEachFile(); }` and everything concerning `title` could be specified in standard blocked-code, `process(hugedirectory).then(function(title) { console.log(title); }).then(function(title) { /*Do something with title*/ });
`. I've stuck with `.then()` here though `.done()` (once or twice) would have the same effect.